# How do I fix dart errors?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Now I want to practice converting the code in Dart, but it gives me this error.

I just wanted to try the data conversion.

Answer (score 1):

its just working fine you might have other error. clean the main function and write it again it might solve the problem.
check out this
https://dartpad.dev/?id=2784dae4ab1808b914799e2c0f59420e